# OS X: Can I run netstat with -w option in logging mode?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, netstat

To trace network traffic rate, I use netstat with -w option:

```
netstat -ib -I en0 -w 5 | awk 'NR > 2 {print "in: " $3 " b/sec; out: " $6 " b/sec"}'
```

It makes netstat to measure data for the five-second intervals, and output them to the terminal. The problem is that I only need one sample. Is there an option like a [-l ] or something, that tells the netstat output X samples and finish? (Like in top -l 1 or nettop -l 1).

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Did you check `man netstat`?

Comment: Of course I checked man netstat :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution via awk (exit after print line with first sample):

```
scripts mx$ netstat -ib -I en0 -w 1 | awk 'NR > 2 {print "in: " $3 " b/sec; out: " $6 " b/sec";exit}'
```